# How to stop navigation to another view controller swift 5

Tags: swift, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift5

When the back button is tapped I'm checking if the save button is enabled. If so, I need to stop the navigation and present an alert to allow the user to save the data. The code below works but the alert is presented after navigation to the previous view controller. How can I stop the navigation and then present the alert?

Thanks in advance.

```swift
    override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)
        {
            if saveBtn_Outlet.isEnabled
            {
                view.sendConfirmationAlert(theTitle: "You have made changes", theMessage: "Data loss will occur", buttonTitle: "OK")
            }
        }
```

Comment: please don't stop the navigation use your custom back button and add this button to navigationbar.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.